# United Kingdom Split Phase Transformer / Centre Tapped Earthed (CTE) / 55V - 0V - 55V - How do you wire the connector?

Tags: transformer, split-phase, iec

I'm working on a weird project which involves making a custom cable for a British CTE Transformer. For those not in the know, these transformers are typically used at jobsites to provide 110V power. There is no neutral contact; instead, there is a -55V, a ground, and a +55V contact.

These type of transformers use IEC 60309 connectors for their outputs, with a key at the 4h (120 degree) position, like [this](http://www.internationalconfig.com/icc6.asp?submit1=Go&item=999-21000-NS).

My question is: Which pin is +55V, and which pin is -55V? I've been looking everywhere for this information. I'd call a company in the UK, but timezones get in the way for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: Which pin is +55V, and which pin is -55V? I've been
> looking everywhere for this information.

At a particular instant in time, one pin will be positive and the other pin will be negative and they will have the same magnitude. Ten milliseconds later and the opposite happens. It happens because the output voltage from a transformer is alternating and not DC: -

[image]

Short story: `it matters not one jot.`

Comment: But the big fat pin is earth!

Comment: @Transistor it certainly is.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks! This is very intuitive. I plan to use a CTE transformer to run a power supply which has 90V-132V/180V-264V auto selectable inputs. This PSU has N, L and G contacts for the input voltage. I'm assuming it won't matter which of the two CTE pins are used for the N and L contacts? As long as the voltage across the N and L contacts on the PSU is +110V or -110V, it looks like it will work.

Comment: I can't say without examining the data sheets but maybe raise it as a new question.

Comment: @Andyaka here's the data sheet. I'll post it as a new topic in a sec. https://www.cui.com/product/resource/vf-d320-dxxxa.pdf

Answer (score 0):

There is no + or – pin.  This is *alternating current*: the + and – reverse 50 times a second!  There is no polarity, so it doesn't matter.