# Powering a switching power supply with a CTE (centre tapped earth) transformer

Tags: power-supply, transformer, mains

This question is an extension of a [previous topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/543886/united-kingdom-split-phase-transformer-centre-tapped-earthed-cte-55v-0v/543899#543899) I posted regarding CTE transformers.

I plan to use a switching power supply for an upcoming project, and I want to supply power to it from a CTE transformer. [See spec sheet for PSU](https://www.cui.com/product/resource/vf-d320-dxxxa.pdf).

As discussed in my last post, CTE transformers have no neutral output. Instead, they have three contacts, where one is ground, and the other two alternate between -55V and +55V such that the voltage difference between the two contacts is +/-110VAC. The PSU, on the other hand, has a "L" and "N" contact for power. Based on the PSU's spec sheet, 110VAC is well within the input range, and I'm assuming that as long as the voltage difference between the "N" and "L" contacts is in the specified range, the device will work.

Am I correct in this assumption? Or am I going to ruin my PSU?

Comment: One isn't ground; one is earthed. Ground can mean 0 volts and ground doesn't mean earthed. Earth means earthed. I think the power supply will work but speak with CUI Inc. I find them to be very helpful and fairly prompt at dealing with this sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

The data sheet does specify neutral and line for the supply and doesn't mention twin hot supplies. The manufacturer's contact details are given at the end of the data sheet; ask them as no-one else can give a definitive answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have one of 110V construction site safety isolation transformers that output 110 VAC that is center-tapped to earth potential so each leg is 55 VAC.

The 115 VAC can be used as usual for connecting into terminals of common equipment such as this power supply.

All it requires is 110 VAC to L an N terminals and the earth to earth terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Electrical code mention dedicated wire. Where is some rules applied, like color, wire can not be interrupted. It becomes neutral the connected to ground at source. In your case the source is transformer. Output of transformer is voltage, just choose output you need. If it is 55-0-55 you can consider 0-55-110, that is the same. 0 considerably is earth, if nothing connected to earth,no 0. But for safety purpose earthing is required.